# Cypress.io cy.request() pass body as var

Tags: javascript, cypress

In Cypress i am trying to make a reusable GET function, however i cant seem to pass through the body as a variable I am using Spotify API for my own testing purpose. The body seems to pass the var name, Any help truly appreciated

Example of body var I am passing:
`const bodyParams= {limit: 20, offset: 0, q: "michael jackson", type: "track", market: "GB"};`

```
Cypress.Commands.add("GETRequest", (requestUrl, bodyParams) => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiURL + requestUrl,
        form: true,
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        },
        body: {
            bodyParams
        }
    });
})
```

[Request Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFARL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have declared the body `bodyParams` as an object, just set it as property for `body:` key.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("GETRequest", (requestUrl, bodyParams) => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiURL + requestUrl,
        form: true,
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        },
        body: bodyParams
    });
})
```